# using mysqldump with where option and a long argument list in bash script

Tags: bash, mysql

I am trying to dump a subset of a table in MySQL with mysqldump. I have the id values of rows that I want to select from the table, stored in a file. When I use these values as a variable as follows:

```
ids=`cat ids.csv`
mysqldump -u root -p db Table --where="id in ($ids)" >> dump.sql
```

I get:

> x.bash: line x: /usr/bin/mysqldump: Argument list too long

I might can try to divide the single line variable $ids (1,2,3,4,..) into shorter lists and call mysqldump in a loop but I am currently not very good with loops in bash scripts.
Or there might be a better way to solve this issue.

Thanks in advance for any help.

**EDIT**

Considering @ajreal's suggestion, 
If I do

```
mysql -u root -p -e "select * into outfile ./dump.sql from db.Table where id in ($ids)"
```

I get "Argument list too long" again.

I get the id values from another environment. The database that I run this script against and the database that I get the id values to use within the where clause are in separate environments.
Additionally, before this step I create the dump file with --ignore-table option, ignoring the "Table" table that I use in the next step. Therefore i would prefer to use mysqldump for that step too.

Comment: negative, save it into file and used **mysql -u root -p.. < YOUR_FILE**

Comment: After some changes, @Dennis' answer was very helpful. Thanks again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Give this a try:

```
xargs -a ids.csv -d '\n' -n 20 sh -c 'mysqldump -u root -p db Table --where="id in ($@)" >> dump.sql' x
```

The `x` is just a dummy value to fill `$0`. Alternatively:

```
xargs -a ids.csv -d '\n' -n 20 sh -c 'mysqldump -u root -p db Table --where="id in ($0 $@)" >> dump.sql'
```

This divides the input file into groups of twenty lines and runs `mysqldump` once for each group. You can probably increase that number safely and can apply a character cap using `--max-chars`. You can use `xargs -a /dev/null --show-limits` to see what the limits are for your system.

```
xargs -a ids.csv -d '\n' -n 1000 --max-chars=100000 sh -c 'mysqldump -u root -p db Table --where="id in ($@)" >> dump.sql' x
```

**Edit:**

Try this Bash script. Set `num` to any reasonable value.

```
#!/bin/bash
ids=$(< ids.csv)

saveIFS=$IFS
IFS=','
array=($ids)               # split into an array using commas as the delimiter
IFS=$saveIFS
array=(${array[@]/%/,})    # add commas back to each element

num=100                    # number of elements to process at a time

for ((i=0; i<${#array[@]}; i+=$num))
do
    list=${array[@]:$i:$num}
    # an excess trailing comma is stripped off in the next line
    mysqldump -u root -p db Table --where="id in ("${list%,}")" >> dump.sql
done
```

Comment: Thank you Dennis. If I try: "xargs -a ids.csv -d '\n' -n 10 --max-chars=2394769 bash -c 'mysqldump -u root -p db MyTable --where="id in ($@)" >> dump.sql' x" with an argument list of 20 elements (1,2,3,..,20) this works fine, however if I run it with the actual file (which is like 1,2,3,4,..100000), I get "xargs: bash: Argument list too long" for all -n values I try. I also got this error with your other reccommendations. It seems like 2394769 is the highest limit I can use for max-chars. It should be worth of reminding that the file consists of a single line in form of (1,2,3,4,..100000)

Comment: @eaykin: Yes, that was a typo. Sorry. Change the `c` to `list`. I'll fix my answer.

Comment: I think "c" should be "list", thank you for the script, I still get "Argument list too long" for every num value (1000, 100, 20, 10, 5, 3 etc.)

Comment: @eaykin: Change `mysqldump` to `echo` and set `num` to `5` and see what the output looks like (post it here, too). Also, post the output of `echo ${#ids}` and `echo ${#array[@]}`.

Comment: @Dennis, i think the problem was about adding commas back to each element. I replaced "array=(${array[@]/%/,})" with "count=0
for i in ${array[@]}; do array[$count]=$i","; ((count++));done" and it seems to be working now. Also I added "--add-drop-table=0" option to mysqldump.

Comment: @eaykin: That `for` loop is a no-op. What happens if you just leave it out?

Comment: @Dennis, loop seems to work fine. i.e. ${array[n]} is turned into "x," from "x" after the loop. Another small change should be IFS=$saveIFS

Comment: @eaykin: Sorry, I didn't see the comma in your comment. Code is hard to read in comments, especially if you don't `enclose it in backticks`. Plus, putting the quotes after the variable instead of like this: `array[$count]="$i,"` makes the code harder to read. I think the real issue was the fact that I omitted the dollar sigh in `IFS=$saveIFS` as you pointed out. Fixing that and going back to `array=(${array[@]/%/,})` should work and be faster than your `for` loop. Sorry for the typos.

Comment: @GabrielBorgesOliveira: It's trying to dump a database named "91859" and I have no idea where that number is coming from. It's likely you have a missing or out of place argument. I can't see your script so I can't help you further.

Comment: @GabrielBorgesOliveira: idk, is that line that starts "db" on a line of its own as shown? It should be on the same line as the `mysqldump` command.

Comment: @GabrielBorgesOliveira: it may not be your problem, but separate your variable assignments on different lines as I have them rather than combining them

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/167763/discussion-between-dennis-williamson-and-gabriel-borges-oliveira).

Answer (score 0):

```
ids.csv => 91916, 91859, 91861, 91894, 92095, 92166, 91796 ...

#!/bin/bash
ids=$(< offer_ids.csv)
saveIFS=$IFS
IFS=',' array=($ids)               # split into an array using commas as the delimiter
IFS=$saveIFS array=(${array[@]/%/,})   # add commas back to each element

num=100                    # number of elements to process at a time

for ((i=0; i<${#array[@]}; i+=$num)) do
    list=${array[@]:$i:$num}
    # an excess trailing comma is stripped off in the next line
    echo "list: " $list
    mysqldump -uroot -h host -p pw --opt --where="offer_id IN ("${list%,}")" db offer_images >> offer_images.sql 
done
```

bash output:

```
offer_id IN (91916, 91859, 91861, 91894, 92095)
mysqldump: Got error: 1049: Unknown database '91859,' when selecting the database
```